# Creating a folder application for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi all
I am new to iPhone programming..I am currently trying to build a folder application iPhone. this application provides user the option to create folders and upload file items in those folders.The application also provides file management operations such as add new folder,delete file items and folder,renaming folders and so on.Can anyone help me on how to develop this application ?

Comment: Not a question for SO. You're trying to get someone to help you make your app, not asking for a solution to a problem you're having.

Comment: i was not asking nyone to make my app but just seeking some advice on how to start it....nyways I did it....

Comment: do you all of it or just a specific part?

Comment: no,only folder creation and accessing these folders

Comment: no offence but dont expect full source code from here, as a starter read up on iOS file sharing in the documentation

Comment: I was only looking for an idea, not the code. I was actually not able to visualize it properly, but now I have got it!

Answer (score 0):

You better use database...that would be more easy..

Comment: Thnx for ur kind advice but i didnt need that actually.

Answer (score 0):

apple docs for NSFileManager are what you are looking for...